# Text between 2 hr's in Android

Tags: android, xml

how can I program a text between two horizontal lines in Android like in Instagram (see picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ODER"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```